# Magento 1.9.3.1 email template for set password by admin not existing in transaction mails?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I got a strange problem with email template for this case and can't find the correct template.

How to reproduce:

**admin user => Admin -> customers -> manage customer ->... -> change password**
Now the user get's a mail. But which template?

It seems like it is not possible to manage this template in admin section in transaction emails?

I thought it would be this but it does not work

**-> System -> Setting  -> Customers -> customer configuration - > change Account Data => changed Email or Password email template**

I tried

**-> create new template + load default template of "changed Email or Password email template"** 
**=> this has only effect on the case if a user itsel changes the password via Frontend / Client Dashboard**

Solution?

After long search i spoted this template:

```
\app\locale\de_DE\template\email\password_new.html

\app\locale\[language]\template\email\password_new.html
```

If i do changes in this template it shows the done changes. But this can't be the correct way to handle it?

I got 5? languages in the store. Do I realy need to modify it on filesystem for each language? and all other templates via admin.

Would be great if someone could share his experience with this specific template.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? Searching now.